# How to remove hashes from array based on if all keys in hash match another hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, unique

I have an array of hashes where each hash is a list of URL parameters from URI::decode_www_form. I want to remove duplicates in this array so that all hashes inside the array have unique parameter keys.

For example if I have

```
arr = [{"update" => "1", "reload" => "true"},
       {"update" => "5", "reload" => "false"},
       {"update" => "9", "reload" => "false"},
       {"update" => "7", "reload" => "true", "newvalue" => "11111"},
       {"page" => "1"}]
```

I would expect to have an array containing only:

```
arr = [{"update" => "1", "reload" => "true"},
       {"update" => "7", "reload" => "true", "newvalue" => "11111"},
       {"page" => "1"}]
```

Where the first three entries are duplicates of each other so only keep one of them, the fourth being unique since it has an extra unique key the first three did not have, and the fifth being unique since it is not the same as any of them.

How would I attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you attempt to solve this problem?  And why do you think that the first three are duplicates?  They are all there different.

Comment: @vgoff Their keys are the same, which is what I am trying to remove duplicates of.

Comment: You can edit the question to clarify that, rather than entries, to unique keys..  I did not rely on the title giving that hint as strongly as I should have. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it like this:

```
tmp = {}
b = arr.select do |h|
  if tmp[h.keys]
    false
  else
    tmp[h.keys] = true
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail to your answer as to why it works for other readers?

Comment: The `tmp` hash is used to track whether we've seen a specific set of keys before. We iterate over each hash in the array and use its keys to return a value from `tmp`. If we get `nil` we haven't seen it before, so we set it to `tmp[h.keys] = true` and return `true`. Otherwise we'll just return `false`. `Array#select` will return only the values returning `true` in the supplied block— the first hash with any unique set of keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{"update" => "1", "reload" => "true"},
       {"update" => "5", "reload" => "false"},
       {"update" => "9", "reload" => "false"},
       {"update" => "7", "reload" => "true", "newvalue" => "11111"},
       {"page" => "1"}]

arr.uniq(&:keys)
  #=> [{"update"=>"1", "reload"=>"true"},
  #    {"update"=>"7", "reload"=>"true", "newvalue"=>"11111"},
  #    {"page"=>"1"}]
```

See the doc for [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) for the case where `uniq` takes a block. In effect, Ruby is doing the following to determine which elements of `arr` to select:

```
a = arr.map(&:keys) 
  #=> [["update", "reload"],
  #    ["update", "reload"],
  #    ["update", "reload"],
  #    ["update", "reload", "newvalue"],
  #    ["page"]] 

a.uniq
  #=> [["update", "reload"], ["update", "reload", "newvalue"], ["page"]]
```

`arr.uniq(&:keys)` has the same effect as:

```
arr.uniq { |h| h.keys }
  #=> [{"update"=>"1", "reload"=>"true"},
  #    {"update"=>"7", "reload"=>"true", "newvalue"=>"11111"},
  #    {"page"=>"1"}]
```

Many view `arr.uniq(&:keys)` as just a short-hand way of writing the above expression with the block. That's OK, but actually `arr.uniq(&:keys)` converts the method (represented by the symbol) `:keys` to a proc and then calls the proc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain what &: does in this instance?